# Is it safe to use a javascript sha1?

Tags: javascript, sha1

I need to do a SHA1 hash, the only option is to use Javascript (due to my client using a 3rd party product)
An SHA1 is required to pass some information to a payment gateway.  so the following info will need to be passed to a SHA1 to convert to a hash (username, password, amount), then passed to a payment gateway

My question is is it safe? ie can't people just view source and see the things I am hashing? is that recommended? is there any other way to do it?

thanks

Comment: that's not enough information to go on.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: So the 3rd party product stores passwords in plain text?

Comment: A SHA1 hash without nonce or secret is totally pointless as signature or security method so the payment gateway is probably terrible. In fact it looks so trivial to hack that if there aren't out of business yet they must be implementing IP restrictions, in which case you simply cannot send client-side requests. The whole story is worrying to say the least.

Comment: Do you hash these three values individually or together? Also which one of these are people not allowed to see?

Comment: The 3rd party product is a form builder, all it does is builds forms using it's own custom scripting or Javascript.  https://script.surveygizmo.com/help

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the hashing algorithm used, with browser-side Javascript, your users will **always** be able to view the page source and see the things you are hashing.

If you're hashing on the server-side, then the source text is not revealed to the browser. It's extremely difficult to "reverse" a SHA-1 hash, but not "impossible" - with enough brute-force power, you could at least find a hash collision (another string which produces the same hash).

SHA-1 is considered secure enough for most purposes. However, it is not considered secure against major, well-funded opponents - with a few million dollars one can hire enough cloud computing resources to break a SHA-1 hash relatively quickly, and this will become progressively cheaper as computing power increases.

If passwords are involved, you should look into BCrypt.

Answer (score 0):

**No, don't do this!**

Password hashing is supposed to make somebody who copies your database unable to use the login information. By hashing on the client side you have exactly the value in the database, that needs to be sent in the request. So an attacker would just disable the hashing and use the database value as the password.

**Quick overview of password hashing:**

Each user has a password, that your service knows. They use it to login. Imagine you stored those in **plain text**. That would be bad in case someone copies your database. So you hash each password with an algorithm like md5 or sha1. The hash can not be used to recreate the password, but you can check a password if it's valid. Problem solved?

Not quite. It's simple to create a **rainbow table** for a hashing algorithm. This way you can quickly look up possible input values for each hash. So you **salt**. This means that each user has a random string that gets appended to the password before hashing, creating a unique hashing function per user. Perfect solution?

Again not quite. If your database is copied, with enough computing power this can be cracked. So your last step is using **iterations**. You don't just append the salt and hash, but you take that result, append the salt again and hash again. You do this a couple hundred times. This way it becomes more expensive for an attacker to brute force attacks. This is what **bcrypt** does. Over time computing power increases, so you should increase the number of iterations.

Comment: A few problems with this:

1. There's nothing to say that the (hashed) password isn't properly hashed and salted /again/ on the server-side. You don't know this, so this is just an assumption.

2. The user doesn't mention anywhere that the hash is being used for authentication. Again this is an assumption.

The question was, "can't people just view source and see the things I am hashing" - the question did not ask about server security or authentication.

Comment: Yes i might have answered a different question :)